# What is the study of language usage types [a question, an answer, a criticism, a complaint an elaboration, etc]?

Tags: terminology

What is the study of language usage types [a question, an answer, a criticism, a complaint an elaboration, etc]?

I've heard ontology and linguistic-typology used interchangeably for this (among others) but not sure either is correct - at best both seem to be metaphors. Is there a widely accepted answer for this discipline? Is this even a discipline :) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called ***speech act theory***. Philosophers J. L. Austin and John Searle were its pioneers. They tried to classify and explain the different ways you can use language to do things (e.g. request information, order someone to do something, make a promise).

Comment: I'm familiar with Austin but haven't read Searle. So, the term for this study is Speech Act Theory, or is this an answer to an area of study (linguistics, phonetics, etc)?

Comment: Speech act theory is probably akin to what some call pragmatics (or is at least a sub-discipline of it).